The name 'Column' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' and 'package:googleapis/analytics/v3.dart'
I'm new to Flutter and making an app that reads a file from google drive. It was working fine but now it's like it's reading the widget "Column" from somewhere else. If I write "Row" instead of Column works fine. It's only when I use Column. I checked the googleapi package and didnt find any class called column. Below I attach code and picture.
import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    //import 'package:flutterdrive/googleDrive.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/analytics/v3.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:core';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class AuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final http.Client _baseClient;
  final Map<String, String> _headers;

  AuthClient(this._baseClient, this._headers);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers.addAll(_headers);
    return _baseClient.send(request);
  }
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  List<drive.File> _documents = [];
  List<String?> fileIDs = [];
  List<List<dynamic>> csvTables = [];

  // Lista de archivos en la clase signindemo

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        //print('ex');
        _getDocuments();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  void _getDocuments() async {

    print('executing');

    final client = http.Client();
    var header = await _currentUser?.authHeaders;
    var authClient = AuthClient(client, header!);
    var api = drive.DriveApi(authClient);
    String? url, id;

    var pageToken = null;
    _documents.clear();
    do {
      // TODO: Change q to search for files, like "name contains 'pdf'"
      // api.files.export(fileId, mimeType);
      var fileList = await api.files.list(
          q: "name contains 'DATA1.csv'",
          pageSize: 20,
          pageToken: pageToken,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          spaces: "drive",
          $fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, thumbnailLink)");
      pageToken = fileList.nextPageToken;

      print('paju');

      _documents.addAll(fileList.files!);
      print(_documents.length);
      for(var i in _documents){
        print(i.id ?? '');
        print(i.name ?? '');
      }




      // print(_documents.first.toString());
    } while (pageToken != null);




    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

 // @override
  Widget _buildBody() {

      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: _currentUser!,
            ),
            title: Text(_currentUser!.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(_currentUser!.email ?? ''),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Get documents'),
            onPressed: _getDocuments,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN Out'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          )

        ],
      );
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
          ),
          body: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: _buildBody(),
          ));
    }
  }

enter image description here

https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/13.1.0/analytics_v3/Column-class.html

Welcome to stackoverflow. Images might be helpful in rare cases, but in general it is better to include error message with your post. It makes is far easier for people to reply as we can then just copy paste.

The error message informs you that Column is defined in the packages flutter and googleapis.
You could try hiding the duplicate class definition (or alternatively use an import prefix).
import 'package:googleapis/analytics/v3.dart' hide Column;

